# Testing of angular 2 component not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

As I am new to angular 2 I have cloned a project from git https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter

and make changes to it.
I added folder banner and three files to it and make changes accordingly in app.module.ts,app.component.ts and app.route.ts.

```
        banner (folder name)

        banner.component.ts

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-banner',
      template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>'
    })
    export class BannerComponent {
     public title = 'Test Tour of Heroes';
    }
        banner.component.spec.ts

    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
    import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';

    describe('BannerComponent', () => {

      let comp: BannerComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;
      let de: DebugElement;
      let el: HTMLElement;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ BannerComponent ], // declare the test component
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

        // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
      });
    });

        index.ts
    export * from './banner.component';
```

When I run the project by `npm start` command it displays the component but when I use `npm test`, it does not test my module. I have named my test by according to convention.
So please help to test my module.

Comment: Put also content of your spec file and component

Comment: Added the code @Skeptor